# Count number of colorings of tetrahedron, where colorings are indistinguishible if one can be reached from another by rotation

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm fairly new to group theory, and here's one problem I'm trying to solve:

We're coloring nodes of tetrahedron in 3 distinct colors, and its edges in 2 distinct colors. We're treating two colorings $c_1, c_2$ of the tetrahedron as equal, if we can rotate tetrahedron colored using $c_1$ to achieve $c_2$. (The rotations are in $\Bbb{R}^3$).

How many of such colorings are there?

I really have no idea how to do it. I heard it's somehow connected to Burnside's lemma, but for me it's a collection of abstract definitions that I can't see how to apply in this concrete example. How to think about such problems?

Comment: Look up Polya Enumeration.  It is directly related to Burnside's lemma.  The wiki page doesn't do a great job of defining everything, but if you read through an example you can probably figure out what everything is.

Comment: Try googling Burnside's Lemma or searching for answers on this site that apply it to counting problems. I've written a couple, but can't write out a full hint/toy example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would  treat this  using Burnside. Using  the variables $a$  for the
vertices and $b$ for the edges, we have three types of rotations for a
total  of  twelve. We  compute  their  cycle  structure and  how  many
assignments they fix.

First  type:  identity,  cycle  structure  $$a_1^4  b_1^6,$$  fixes
$$3^4\times 2^6$$ colorings.

Second type:  $180$ degree rotations about an axis passing through  midpoints of opposite edges, cycle structure 
$$3\times  a_2^2 b_1^2 b_2^2,$$ fixes $$3\times 3^2 \times 2^2 \times 2^2$$ colorings.

Third type:  rotations by  $120$ degrees and  $240$ degrees  about an
axis  passing through the  center of  a face  to the  opposite vertex,
cycle structure $$4\times 2\times a_1 a_3 b_3^2,$$ fixes 
$$4\times 2\times 3 \times 3 \times 2^2$$ colorings.

Average over $12$ permutations by Burnside is
$$\frac{1}{12} (5184 +432 + 288) = 492.$$

There is an extensive list of Polya / Burnside computations by various users at [MSE meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335).

**Remark.** The space of possible configurations is within reach of total enumeration. The following Maple program does this and the result of the computation is $$492.$$

```
v :=
proc()
    option remember;
    local res, orbit, vind, eind, vcol, ecol,
    cols, vperms, vperm, edges, eperms, eperm,
    q, v1, v2, p;

    vperms :=
    [[1,2,3,4], # identity
     [2,1,4,3], # 180 degree rotations
     [3,4,1,2],
     [4,3,2,1],
     [2,3,1,4], # 120/240 degree rotations
     [3,1,2,4],
     [1,3,4,2],
     [1,4,2,3],
     [3,2,4,1],
     [4,2,1,3],
     [2,4,3,1],
     [4,1,3,2]];

    edges := table(); q := 1;

    for v1 to 4 do
        for v2 from v1+1 to 4 do
            edges[{v1, v2}] := q;
            q := q+1;
        od;
    od;


    eperms := [];

    for vperm in vperms do
        eperm := [];

        for v1 to 4 do
            for v2 from v1+1 to 4 do
                eperm :=
                [op(eperm),
                 edges[{vperm[v1], vperm[v2]}]];
            od;
        od;

        eperms := [op(eperms), eperm];
    od;


    res := {};

    for vind from 3^4 to 2*3^4-1 do
        vcol := convert(vind, base, 3);

        for eind from 2^6 to 2*2^6-1 do
            ecol := convert(eind, base, 2);

            orbit := {};

            for p to 12 do
                cols := [seq(vcol[vperms[p][q]], q=1..4)];
                cols :=
                [op(cols),
                 seq(ecol[eperms[p][q]], q=1..6)];

                orbit := orbit union {cols};
            od;

            res := res union {orbit};
        od;
    od;


    nops(res);
end;
```

There is a variation on this that may be slightly easier to read.

```
v :=
proc()
    option remember;
    local res, orbit, vind, eind, vcol, ecol,
    cols, vperms, vperm, edges, eperms, eperm,
    q, v1, v2, p;

    vperms :=
    [[1,2,3,4], # identity
     [2,1,4,3], # 180 degree rotations
     [3,4,1,2],
     [4,3,2,1],
     [2,3,1,4], # 120/240 degree rotations
     [3,1,2,4],
     [1,3,4,2],
     [1,4,2,3],
     [3,2,4,1],
     [4,2,1,3],
     [2,4,3,1],
     [4,1,3,2]];

    edges := table();

    edges[{1,2}] := 1;
    edges[{1,3}] := 2;
    edges[{1,4}] := 3;
    edges[{2,3}] := 4;
    edges[{2,4}] := 5;
    edges[{3,4}] := 6;


    eperms := [];

    for vperm in vperms do
        eperm := [];

        for v1 to 4 do
            for v2 from v1+1 to 4 do
                eperm :=
                [op(eperm),
                 edges[{vperm[v1], vperm[v2]}]];
            od;
        od;

        eperms := [op(eperms), eperm];
    od;


    res := {};

    for vind from 3^4 to 2*3^4-1 do
        vcol := convert(vind, base, 3);

        for eind from 2^6 to 2*2^6-1 do
            ecol := convert(eind, base, 2);

            orbit := {};

            for p to 12 do
                cols := [seq(vcol[vperms[p][q]], q=1..4)];
                cols :=
                [op(cols),
                 seq(ecol[eperms[p][q]], q=1..6)];

                orbit := orbit union {cols};
            od;

            res := res union {orbit};
        od;
    od;


    nops(res);
end;
```